# Integral by substitution of an absolute value of a derivative

Tags: integration, absolute-value, substitution

I found the deformation below in a book. Could you explain how is it possible?
\begin{equation}
\int_\alpha^\beta \left|\frac{d\bf{e}}{ds}\right|ds =  \int_\alpha^\beta \left|\frac{d\bf{e}}{dt}\right|\frac{dt}{ds}ds=\int_a^b \left|\frac{d\bf{e}}{dt}\right|dt
\end{equation}
where $a\leq t\leq b$ corresponds to $\alpha \leq s \leq \beta$.

I think it does not make a big difference, but in that book, $\left|\frac{d\bf{e}}{ds}\right|$ was written as $(\frac{d\bf{e}}{ds} \cdot \frac{d\bf{e}}{ds})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ instead.

Comment: What's $\bf e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first transformation is a result of using the chain rule. Suppose that $t$ is a function of $s$, then,
$$
  \frac{d\textbf{e}}{ds} = \frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds} \tag{1}
$$

Taking the norm of (1) yields,
$$
\begin{align}
  \left| \frac{d\textbf{e}}{ds} \right| =& \left(  \frac{d\textbf{e}}{ds} \cdot  \frac{d\textbf{e}}{ds} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
=& \left[\frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt} \cdot \frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt}\left(\frac{dt}{ds} \right)^2 \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
=& \left| \frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt}  \right|\frac{dt}{ds}
\end{align}
$$

The final part is a result of using [Integration by Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), which gives that,
$$
  \int_{t(\alpha)}^{t(\beta)}\left| \frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt} \right| dt = \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} \left| \frac{d\textbf{e}}{dt}  \right|\frac{dt}{ds} ds
$$